# Is it scam when this sugar daddy ask me to pay like called "international fees" to receive the money?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, sugar-daddy

So this sugar daddy dm me and says he wants to be my sugar daddy. we've been talking for a days and then he asked me about my paypal account.

Now he's sending me the money but he said i need to pay like international fees to receive the money. He said i can pay bitcoin. Is this scam or not?? i feel and know it's scam but i just want to ask for clarification.

Comment: But check your resume, you must have some other skills / Do you have any other skills ... like typing? youtube.com/watch?v=9x-TriYjnXs

Answer (score 8):

Yes. 100% scam. Don't give this person any money, or any more of your time.

Sometimes the answer is really that simple. Sorry for the days you spent on this scammer, and I'm glad it wasn't more time or money.

Comment: I would add to report the scam to your local law enforcement _and_ to whatever platform provided the DM function.  Not likely to accomplish much, but it MIGHT get the criminal put in jail.